# How do I make table size fixed and only adjust the size of the cells based on the amount of them?

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have created a table of divs that turn red when you hover over them.

```
var createGrid = function(width, height){

for (var i = 16; i <= height+15; i++)
{
    $('<tr></tr>', {
        'id'   : 'tr' + i
    }).appendTo($('#one'));

    for (var j = 16; j <= width+15; j++) {
        $('<td></td>', {
            'id' : 'td' + i + j
        }).appendTo($('#tr' + i));

        $('#td' + i + j).wrapInner('<div class="div" />');
    };

$('div').css({
    'border' : '1px solid black',
    'height' : '20px',
    'width'  : '20px'
    });

};  };
```

and I also have a way to ask the user what width/height the table will have when they click a button.

```
$(this).on('click', '#reset', function() {
$('tbody').remove();


var w = +prompt("width?");
var h = +prompt("height?");
createGrid(w, h);  });
```

However, the table gets larger when there are more cells. How do I make the table size fixed, but make the cell's bigger when there are fewer of them and smaller when there are more of them?

Answer (score 0):

use css to set

```
table{
 width:"500" 
}
```

you already define the width of a cell

```
 $('div').css({
        'border' : '1px solid black',
        'height' : '20px',
        'width'  : '20px'
        });
```

try to use 10% or other percentage to replace the number

Comment: Thank you for answering, but that does not adjust the size of the cells, only makes the spaces between them larger.

Comment: you already define the width of an cell .                                                                     $('div').css({
    'border' : '1px solid black',
    'height' : '20px',
    'width'  : '20px'
    });try to use 10% or other percentage to replace the number